# DBUnit testing in Java with multiple schemas

Tags: java, dbunit

I have a class that work with DataBase (MySql). And I want to test this class. In database are many schemas and tables, and my class work with alot of them. What I need to use for test all of this database? I try to use HSQLDB database to load all schemas and tables from database in memory, but I can't load multiple schemas. Is other suggestions? Maybe using other databases or framework for testing?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a design problem.  Your class seems to follow the [God Object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GodObject) anti-pattern.  Given that it seems to need to access many tables and schemas, I think you might be over reaching.

You need to trim down what your class does and probably split it into multiple classes.